# Modulus in C isn't working

Tags: c

So, I'm having a little problem with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int centimeters, feet, inches;
    printf("Please enter an amount in centimeters\n");
    scanf("%i", &centimeters);
    getchar();
    inches = (centimeters/2.54);
    feet = inches % 12;
    printf("\n%i", &feet);
    return 0;
}
```

No matter what number I input, the program thinks that the answer is 2358852. I know for a fact that 24 centimeters is not more than 2 million feet. If it matters, I am using Dev C++ to compile.

Comment: `printf("\n%i", &feet);` -> `printf("\n%i", feet);` You are 'trying' to print the address of the variable

Comment: For future reference: For the next couple of years, when something doesn't work for you, you're doing something wrong. You don't know enough about programming yet to get to the edge cases where it's even possible for compiler (or even hardware) bugs to go unnoticed.

Comment: "select isn't broken": http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/

Comment: @Cubic I would agree with you except the part saying that the bugs are at the edge cases only. I have encountered some (confirmed) bugs in a very simple cases...

Comment: @EugeneSh. That happens (I've run into one compiler bug and at least one library (in something that was presumably used by more than me) bug I can remember). It's practically and morally better to assume it doesn't though.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong

```
printf("\n%i", &feet);
```

it should be

```
printf("\n%i", feet);
/*             ^ no & here */
```

`printf("\n%i", &feet);` prints the [address of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) `feet`, and not it's value.

Your program also assumes that the `scanf()`ed value was read successfuly, you must check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure that it succeeded

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int centimeters, feet, inches;

    printf("Please enter an amount in centimeters\n");
    if (scanf("%i", &centimeters) == 1)
    {
        getchar();

        inches = centimeters / 2.54;
        feet   = inches % 12;

        printf("\n%i", feet);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

also, apparently the formula is wrong as mentioned in another answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Your modulus calculation for `feet` is wrong. It should be

```
feet = inches / 12;
inches %= 12;
printf("\n%i feet, %i inches", feet, inches);
```